# How do I fix undefined and the arg not reading the correct line in the split?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So, my command looks like this: +coords SpawnObject( "Truck_01_Covered_Blue", "6642.018555 461.256714 15280.805664", "-163.117828 -4.038700 1.684388" ); and my code is this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return; 
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('wing!');
    } else if (command === 'coords') {
        var [SpawnObject, BuildingName, pos, yaw] = args; {
            var cords = pos.split(" ")
            var a = yaw.split(" ")
            var x = cords[0]
            var y = cords[1]
            var z = cords[2]
            var a = a[0]
            var b = (a+90) - 360 * Math.floor((a+90)/360)

           console.log(`${`<pos x=${x}" y="${y}" z="${z}" a="${b}" />`}`);
         }
    } 
});
```

I then get a result of this:

pos x="6642.018555" y="undefined" z="undefined" a="101.25671490000002" /

It will read the first number and place it and then it wont read the other numbers and Ive no idea where its getting a="101.25671490000002" from.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse your self by using double quotes and `+`.
[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can be nested.

Line you should change

```
message.channel.send(`Co-ords: ${`<pos x="${x}",y="${y}", z="${z}", a="${b}" />`}`);
```

```js
const SpawnObject = ( pos, coords, yaw) => {
   if (!pos || !coords || !yaw) throw new Error('Invalid Parameter')
   var cords = pos.split(" ")
    var   a = yaw.split(" ")
    var  x = cords[0] || ''
    var  y = cords[1] || ''
    var  z = cords[2] || ''
    var   a = a[0] || ''
    var  b = (a+90) - 360 * Math.floor((a+90)/360) || null
    console.log('Your codes -', `Co-ords: ${("<pos x=" + '"' + x + '"', "y=" + '"' + y + '"', "z=" + '"' + z + '"', "a=" + '"' + b + '"' + " />")}`)
    console.log('Updated codes -', `Co-ords: ${`<pos x="${x}",y="${y}", z="${z}", a="${b}" />`}`);
    
}
    
    
SpawnObject("Truck_01_Covered_Blue","8055.317871 208.090668 11192.843750", "-0.037681 -0.921074 6.630672" )
```

Comment: Im still getting the same problem from it.

Comment: When you click on **Run code snippet** does it work? Does it show what you desire? If it does then there's nothing wrong with this line of code. The error may have occured from other part of your codes which you may not have showed us.

Comment: It does not work. You gave no function for it to pull from the names and to calculate the values of each number and place them in the response. I want the function to take this line of values from the command (which will never be the same): SpawnObject( "Truck_01_Covered_Blue", "8055.317871 208.090668 11192.843750", "-0.037681 -0.921074 6.630672" ); , use the function to get everything situated with the math and splitting it up and then output it to message.channel.send(`Co-ords: ${`<pos x="${x}",y="${y}", z="${z}", a="${b}" />`}`);  .

Comment: If you look at your question posted, you did not give us any example values, are we suppose to guess? The answer corrected the error you had in your `message.channel.send` codes. Everything else is up to your own customisation.

Comment: I said my exact problem and its still happening. Even with your "updated codes" it gives the same error that x is not defined.

Comment: I've updated the codes with the strings you provided, it doesn't return your problem. You sure your problem exist in the code you posted in question? Because the moment you defined `var x`, the only reason it return undefined would be because you did not pass in `coords` in your function call. I added in condition to set it to empty string

Comment: Now that I took it out of a collection it some what works. But it will only return the values that are attached with this line of code: SpawnObject("Truck_01_Covered_Blue","8055.317871 208.090668 11192.843750", "-0.037681 -0.921074 6.630672" ) that you showed in the code. I need it to be able to read what the numbers are from the command and output them, having the SpawnObject in the code will just constantly log those numbers from the code and not from the user input

Comment: @SeanSmall Sorry, since those codes are only visible to you, you have to fix them yourself.